# I have an issue with "collections" module in Python

Tags: python, collections

I need to remake sentences (which are opened from a txt file) in a way that a letter in a word is repeated as many times as it is encountered in the word itself.

Example:

"I need a drink" must become: "I neeeed a drink"

Here is the code. It's pretty screwed up, I know:

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter()

words_title = []

new_word = ''

new_word2 = ''

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as file:                   
    reading = file.read()
    splitted = reading.split()

words_title = [word.title() for word in reading]

for word in words_title:
    for wor in word:
        for wo in word:
            c[wo] += 1
            new_word += word

for word2 in new_word:
    word2 = word2 * c[word2]
    new_word2 += word2

print(c)
print(new_word)
print(new_word2)
```

Comment: What part of the code are you asking about? What do you expect it to do, what does it do instead, and where are you stuck trying to fix it? I'm pretty sure `for wor in word: for wo in word:` isn't a useful thing to do, but I have no idea what you _wanted_ it to do, so I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: A middle part, to be precise. In my example it uses 4 letters in the place where 2 letters would be (like "ccccooooccccoooonut"). I want the word to be "ccooccoonut".

Comment: What you're doing with that nested loop is looping over every pair of characters. For example, if `word` is `'abc'`, you're effectively looping over `'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc'`. Except that you're not using `wor` anymore, so you're actually just looping over `'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'`. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I would suggest not including the file operations in the question as it is irrelevant. The question should be simplified to use `start_string = "whatever"` instead of loading it from a file. It would also be easier for you and us to test it that way.

Comment: I have a full sentence. I should divide it into words, then divide the words into letters and only THEN I should loop over the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt on what I guess you want to do:

```
from collections import Counter

start_string = '  coconuts taste great '

words = start_string.strip().split() # get single words from string

for word in words: # loop over individual words
    c = Counter(word) # count letters
    new_word = ''
    for w in word: # loop over letters in the original word
        new_word += w*c[w] # write the new word
    print new_word

#ccooccoonuts
#ttastte
#great
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "I need a drink"
words = sentence.split()

out_sentence = ""

for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        for _ in range(word.count(letter)):
            out_sentence += letter
    out_sentence += " "

out_sentence = out_sentence[:-1]

print(out_sentence)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner along the lines of Dux's answer, but using a generator expression and joining all the character sequences at the end instead of at each iteration:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'I need a drink, coconut'

print(''.join(c * n[c] for w in s.split() for n in (Counter(w + ' '),) for c in w + ' '))
# Output: I neeeed a drink, ccooccoonut
```

Note that the second 'for' only iterates once in order to assign the Counter object to `n`; this little trick ensures that a new Counter object is only created for each word `w` rather than for each character `c`.